# Jquery Имитация клика получается в цикле, а надо не более одного раза

Tags: jquery, ajax

Аяксом получаю страницу где есть пользовательская форма загрузки изображений.

И так как страница приходит аяксом, то функции для это формы перестают срабатывать. 
А когда переписал имитацию клика (с помощью подсказки рубахи:)), то имитация клика начала срабатывать, но перестала инициализироваться функция самой загрузки.

Ничего лучше не придумав, я решил подгружать файл с функциями для формы.

Вот как выглядит весь скрипт

$(function(){

```
var ul = $('#upload ul');

$('#content').on('click', '#drop a', function (evt){
    // Имитация клика по input
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
});

// Инициализация jQuery File Upload plugin
$('#upload').fileupload({

    // Контейнер для drag-and-drop
    dropZone: $('#drop'),

    // Функция, вызываемая после выбора файла
    add: function (e, data) {
        // Автоматическая загрузка файла после его добавления
        var jqXHR = data.submit();
    /* попытка обновить контейнер с новыми фотками, но фотка не успевает загрузится :( */
    $.get('/algo/get/get_user_photos.php', {}, function(data){
        $('.photo_user_list').html(data);
    }, 500);
    },

    fail:function(e, data){
        // Ошибка
        data.context.addClass('error');
    }

});

// Отмена стандартного действия брацзера, если выполнено действие drop
$(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

а вот форма

```
    <form id="upload" method="post" action="/algo/set/set_user_photos.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="drop">
            <a>Загрузить новые фотографии</a>
            <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
        </div>

        <div class="photo_user_list">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: > то я вновь подгружаю скрипт обработчик

То есть вы хотите оставить бредовый вариант реализации, а посвятить себя созданию прекрасного костыля? ))

Comment: К стыду моему ничего лучшего не могу придумать. Знание js не то.

Comment: @Tchort, может тогда пойти в сторону более продуманного решения задачи? Попробуйте коротко, но четко описать всё задуманное. Последовательные действия пользователя и ответные реакции на эти действия, которые ожидаете увидеть.

Comment: более подробно описал случившееся :)

Comment: @Tchort,говорите, что подгружаете всю страницу вместе с JS-скриптами? Почему не подгружать просто саму форму? После того, как форма загружена в определенный блок, надо сразу же переинициализировать плагин "fileupload". О способах инициализации, вы могли [читать в документации](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#initialization).

Comment: Либо я не правильно переинициализирую, либо не арбайтен.
Вместе с формой подгружаю скрипт

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#upload').fileupload('enable');
});
</script>

Comment: а, все понял, не правильно инициализировал) спасибо :))